# when i swipe the swipeRefreshLayout , it jump to 8 card belower

Tags: android, json, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout` in the layout when i swipe that , that is load `json` from server , every

thing is ok but when i swipe that  it jump to 7_8 card belower from the last json element .

this is my layout => `tab_fragment_3.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/xml_swipe_refresh_layout_tab_fragment_3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/xmlRecyclerViewtabFragment3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and this is the fragment that json load in to that.

`TabFragment3.java` :

```
package ghandak.ghandshekan.com.ghandak.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import ghandak.ghandshekan.com.ghandak.R;
import ghandak.ghandshekan.com.ghandak.adapters.PostRecyclerAdapter;
import ghandak.ghandshekan.com.ghandak.app.AppController;
import ghandak.ghandshekan.com.ghandak.models.PostData;


public class TabFragment3 extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener{
    private RecyclerView allContentRecyclerView;
    private String url  = "http://hello.herokuapp.com/api/news/?format=json";
    private List<PostData> postDataList = new ArrayList<PostData>();
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    //====================================================================================== onCreateView
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_3 , container , false);
        allContentRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.xmlRecyclerViewtabFragment3);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        allContentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.xml_swipe_refresh_layout_tab_fragment_3);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        //swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors();



        return view;
    }

    //====================================================================================== onCreate


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sendJsonRequest();
    }

    //====================================================================================== sendjsonRequest
    private void sendJsonRequest() {

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                postDataList.clear();
                parseJsonResponse(response);
                //==========setting adapter to the recyclerview  <==
                allContentRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PostRecyclerAdapter(getActivity() ,postDataList));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

    }

    //====================================================================================== parsjsonResponse()
    private void parseJsonResponse(JSONArray response) {
        if(response == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ریسپانس خالی هستش", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else {
            Log.d("parsejsonresponse", "response khali nist");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length()  ; i++ ){

                try {

                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ریسپانس میگیرم ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    JSONObject currentPost = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    //Log.d("currentPost", "currentPost ro gereftam");

                    PostData postData = new PostData();
                    postData.setTitle(currentPost.getString("title"));
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity() , currentPost.getString("title") , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    postData.setCreate(currentPost.getString("create"));

                    postDataList.add(postData);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        sendJsonRequest();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove LinearLayout if you dont use it.

Comment: thank you patrik for our answer but i have a problem with taht

Comment: use `setSelection(0)` after updating data

Comment: can you explain this code more , i dont know where i write this .